# How to show $f(x)=\int^x_1\sqrt{2+\cos^3t}\;dt$ is injective function?

Tags: calculus, integration, functions

Show $\;f(x)=\int^x_1\sqrt{2+\cos^3t}\;dt , \;x\in\Bbb R$ is  injective and if $a=f(\frac\pi2)$,   then  find            $\;(f^{-1})'(a)$

How can I compute that integral?

or should we do like

Let $a,b\in\Bbb R$  and $f(a)=f(b)$ and $\frac{d(f(a))}{dt}=\frac{d(f(b))}{dt}$

any hints would be great

Comment: **Hint:** If $f$ is strictly increasing, it is injective.

Comment: Use the [derivative of the inverse function theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_functions_and_differentiation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Injectivity: Using Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, the derivative $f'(x) = \sqrt{2+\cos^3 x}$, which has the range $[1, \sqrt 3]$. Since the derivative is always positive, $f(x)$ is injective.

2) Let $\displaystyle f(x) = y$

Then $\displaystyle x = f^{-1}(y)$

$\displaystyle \frac{dx}{dy} = (f^{-1})'(y)$

$\displaystyle \frac{1}{f'(x)} = (f^{-1})'(y) $

$\displaystyle \frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(y))} = (f^{-1})'(y) $

Hence $\displaystyle (f^{-1})'(x) = \frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(x))}$

So $\displaystyle (f^{-1})'(a) = \frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(a))} = \frac{1}{f'(\frac{\pi}{2})} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 +\cos^3 \frac{\pi}{2}}} = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt 2$

Comment: thanks. if derivative is always positive that means f(x) is increasing or stricly increasing?

Comment: Strictly increasing. As the derivative is always positive, the function always increases in the positive $x$ direction.